# Add permanent labels by using proc datasets

Tags: sas

Say I have created a dataset. Now I want to add permanent labels by using proc datasets. How?

My code is not working:

```
*Set up the library for this assignment;
libname  "C:\users\someplace";

*Create a fileref for this data set;
filename bank "C:\Users\someplace\bankdata.txt";
 * blah blah
data MyBankInfo;
infile bank;

input NAME & $14.
      ACCT $
      BALANCE
      RATE
     ;

*Assign the permanent labels;
proc datasets lib=MyBankInfo;

Label NAME = 'Name(character)'
    ACCT = 'Account(character)'
    BALANCE = 'Balance(numeric)'
    RATE = 'Rate(numeric)'
     ;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: You aren't creating a permanent data set here, this will disappear when your session is over. Was that your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modify` tells SAS what dataset you want to modify the labels on.  `lib` tells SASwhat library (directory) to modify datasets from.

```
*Assign the permanent labels;
proc datasets lib=work;

modify mybankinfo;
Label NAME = 'Name(character)'
    ACCT = 'Account(character)'
    BALANCE = 'Balance(numeric)'
    RATE = 'Rate(numeric)'
     ;
run;
quit;
```